# How to create custom query for getting user id in Repository Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dql

My tasks is to get the current user products. I have a listCartProductsAction in CartController with following lines of code:

```
  public function listCartProductsAction()
    {
        $cartProducts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:CartProduct')->findByUser($this->getUser()->getId());

        return $this->render('cart/cart.view.html.twig', array(
            'cartProducts' => $cartProducts
        ));
    }
```

In the CartRepository im trying to create a query which get the products of current user, but it's definitely not correct:

```
 public function findByUser($user)
    {
        $query = $this
            ->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT u FROM AppBundle:Cart u WHERE u.IDENTITY = ?1")
            ->setParameter(1, $user->getUser()->getId());
        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

When i try to display the products in the twig template, i got exception:

> Call to a member function getUser() on integer

Any ideas how to prevent this error ?
After var_dump($cartProducts);

```
`array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(AppBundle\Entity\Cart)[898]
      private 'id' => int 1
      private 'userId' => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[765]
          private 'id' => int 8
          private 'email' => string 'rumen@abv.bg' (length=12)
          private 'username' => string 'Rumkata97' (length=9)
          private 'name' => string 'Rumen Panchev' (length=13)
          private 'password' => string '$2y$13$1QVBSg.uPPMdln6N/5/3DOjubxWtpkZYYtWlHEPc2S.JPx24Qz3Ce' (length=60)
          private 'image' => string 'c066099438bc7e258cc0ba21fa9d1b31' (length=32)
          private 'image_form' => null
          private 'products' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[789]
              ...
          private 'role' => string 'ROLE_ADMIN' (length=10)
          private 'cart' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[815]
              ...
      private 'dateCreated' => 
        object(DateTime)[900]
          public 'date' => string '2017-04-25 17:21:58.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
      private 'dateUpdated' => 
        object(DateTime)[904]
          public 'date' => string '2017-04-25 18:02:30.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
  1 => 
    object(AppBundle\Entity\Cart)[899]
      private 'id' => int 3
      private 'userId' => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[765]
          private 'id' => int 8
          private 'email' => string 'rumen@abv.bg' (length=12)
          private 'username' => string 'Rumkata97' (length=9)
          private 'name' => string 'Rumen Panchev' (length=13)
          private 'password' => string '$2y$13$1QVBSg.uPPMdln6N/5/3DOjubxWtpkZYYtWlHEPc2S.JPx24Qz3Ce' (length=60)
          private 'image' => string 'c066099438bc7e258cc0ba21fa9d1b31' (length=32)
          private 'image_form' => null
          private 'products' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[789]
              ...
          private 'role' => string 'ROLE_ADMIN' (length=10)
          private 'cart' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[815]
              ...
      private 'dateCreated' => 
        object(DateTime)[901]
          public 'date' => string '2017-04-27 14:28:53.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
      private 'dateUpdated' => 
        object(DateTime)[902]
          public 'date' => string '2017-04-27 15:06:50.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is pretty simple: The `findByUser` function gets the `int` id of the user (through `$this->getUser()->getId()`), but still wants to call some functions on it, which of course doesn't work. Instead, the line in the `findByUser` function should be:

`->setParameter(1, $user);`

Comment: Ok i've edited it and now i got this error: Invalid parameter format, ? given, but :<name> or ?<num> expected.

Comment: Ok, I'm actually not that familiar with the doctrine dql, but I think, you need to replace `IDENTITY` with `id` (after a quick google after `IDENTITY`).

Comment: Ok now there are no errors, but the output in the twig template is empty. I've edited my question and posted the twig template.

Comment: I just realized: it obviously shouldn't be `u.id = ?1`, but `u.**userId** = ?1`. You want search by the id of the user, not the id of the CartItem. Sorry.

Comment: Im not sure i understand u, now i got syntax error.  Expected Literal, got '*'

Comment: Oh, the asterisks were supposed to make the text bold, but that didn't work. Remove them. It should be `u.userId`.

Comment: Ok now it's working but still not displayed in the twig i tried the example above, but doesnt work. I will be very happy if u give me some advices how to print the products

Comment: Maybe do a `dump_var($cartProducts);` before the `return` statement in the php code to inspect the `$cartProducts` variable? Because the `Cart` class doesn't have a field or function named `product`, so I would expect errors from twig.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Skype and not enough reputation for the chat. Maybe use something else? Or you could mark my answer as accepted? Then I would have enough reputation.

Comment: What about facebook ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142860/discussion-between-rumen-panchev-and-suncrasher).